# Optimize search to match all criteria

Tags: php, mysql

I have db table clients which have 4 columns : `id`, `gender`, `nationality`, `county`. And let's say that I need to find x records that match all criteria. For criteria example 
200 males 200 females ||| 100 americans, 100 russians, 100 lithuanians and 100 swedens ||| 50 from cansas. 150 from vilnius, 200 from kaunas.

I need to find as low as possible clients because I want to send them invitation emails.

Comment: Have you tryed a query?

Comment: So the maximum records in this case whould be 400? Because you want to send to 200 males and 200 females living in the USA, rusland, lithuanian, sweden and cansas (is cansas even a country sounds more a state in the USA?)

Comment: You don't see point here. Ofc you can select 200 males thant 200 females than 100 lithuanians and etc than distinct and you will get answer for example 600 clients but its not effective

Comment: "You don't see point here" yea because your question isn't clear..

Comment: the transsexual bi-nationals are really going to make this difficult.